# Neo4j Py2neo not updating node properties

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Writing python program to fetch existing `Neo4j` node and update properties using `py2neov3 package`.

Movie node has title & year properties. Have a python dictionary with list of movies to be added.

I have tried below options, movie node is getting added. But year property is not updated.

**Option#1:** Use Py2neo OGM. Start transaction, create Movie object, populate title, invoke merge, populate year, invoke push, finally commit

**Option#2:** Instead of OGM (Commented code below), use Node function, invoke merge and push.

I have done with above mentioned options, but it didn't work for me. Python version 3.5.2

Code:

```
try:  
tx = gdb.begin()   ##gdb is Graph object 
for x in moviedict.keys():
 m1 = Movie()
 m1.title = moviedict[x]['title']
 tx.merge(m1)
 m1.year = moviedict[x]['year']
 tx.graph.push(m1)       
tx.commit()
"""Option2 for x in moviedict.keys():
   m1 = Node('Movie',title=moviedict[x]['title'])
   gdb.merge(m1)
   m1['year'] = moviedict[x]['year']
   gdb.push(m1)
 """
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use dictionaries, because I wanted the example to be both short and runnable

```
    import py2neo
    import py2neo.ogm

    from py2neo import Graph
    from py2neo.ogm import GraphObject, Property

    class Movie(GraphObject):
        __primarykey__ = "title"

        title = Property()
        released = Property()

    def authenticateAndConnect():
        py2neo.authenticate('localhost:7474', 'user', 'password')
        return Graph('http://localhost:7474/default.graphdb/data/')     

    def foo():
        graph = authenticateAndConnect()
        movie = Movie.select(graph).where("_.title = 'The Matrix Reloaded'").first()
        movie.released = 2017
        graph.push(movie)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        foo()
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually trying to update or add if movie does not exist using merge, followed by push which is adding movie with out year.Your code works for update.